# Android, many buttons click in one moment

Tags: android

I'm trying to make simple reaction game on android.

In my layout I have 6 buttons (red, green, etc). When You click "your" button yours should be visible and all of rest should be invisible. I made that and it works fine, but...

The problem is that when I click on 2 or more buttons in one moment all of buttons disappear.

There is no errors and warnings on console.

For example one button defined in my code:

```
buttonRed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
buttonRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonBlack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonGreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonOrange.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonBlue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonWhite.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Thank you for any help : )

Comment: Do you ever set the buttons back to visible? Or maybe you are wanting to set the other buttons to disabled also when other buttons are clicked. Just a thought as I'm a little unclear on exactly what your issue is.

Comment: How do you make clicks on "2 or more buttons in one moment"?

Comment: I have button "new category" and this button is making all 6 (color) buttons visible. The problem is that it should work like this: (6 buttons, different colors; click button new category for example "movie", and then who knows movie starting with "B" press his button and he answer) and the problem is that when I click any 1 button in a moment it works, but when for example 2 players press buttons in one time all disappear (6 buttons are invisible, the right way is to 5 buttons invisible 1 visible)..

Answer (score 1):

In every button click listener do these steps:

1- make all button invisible
2- make target button visible

I think you had forgotten step 2.